# How to navigate on different componet using material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, mern

How to navigate on a different component using material UI

here is the code of my drawer list

```
  <List>
          {['POS', 'Stock', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
    </List>
```

I would like to navigate on the stock page

App.js

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        < Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Login/>} />
          <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
          <Route exact path='/product' element={<Product/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

I want that if I will click this listItem element so that component will open
here is my GUI

[image]

Comment: don't you use react router?

Comment: I am using in the app.js

Comment: <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        < Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Login/>} />
          <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
          <Route exact path='/product' element={<Product/>}/>

        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle routing in this case:

1. `<Link to="<route>">` provided by react-router itself. You can wrap your ListItem with it and it will work as an anchor tag and redirect to the page. [Ref](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)
2. You can also handle it by adding an onClick method to ListItem and passing the route you want to redirect to. Using the `useHistory` hook, the history object can be instantiated and the method `history.push(<route>)` will do the job. [Ref](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: Thanks for replying, history. push is deprecated now and instead of it now react introduce navigate, but i am confuse that how i can link on listItem for instance when we use in listItem in bootstrap we can give href to li however how can i perform the same thing here

Comment: @ZaryabKhan If you are using the latest version of react-router you can still add a onClick handler to list Item and use the navigate hook. On another note, `<Link to="/dashboard"><ListItem>Content..</ListItem></Link>` should also work.